# How can i fit this comma problem with CSV file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code that creates a CVS file with the CF7 information the customer has provided, and it is attached into the mail I receive, the code is into functions.php.

The problem I have is that if a customer puts a comma into any field, like if he put on the name field John, Smith, it breaks the CSV

Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

```
//Create the shortcode which will set the value for the DTX field
function cf7dtx_counter(){
    $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;  //Increment the current count
    return $val;
}
add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

//Action performed when the mail is actually sent by CF7
function cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter(){
    $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count
    update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val); //Update the settings with the new count
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter');

// Add this to functions.php //
// Create CSV by scraping email using before_send_mail action //
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_csv_creation' );
function cf7_csv_creation($cf7) {
  // Allow to target the ID of specific form  //
  $form_id = $cf7->id();
  // Check certain form by ID - remove this IF statement if not specific //
    // Make sure the file is saved into wp-content to retieve it within WPCF7 settings as an attachement //
    $user_register_csv = 'wp-content/uploads/csvs/csvreserva.csv';
    // Create file contents - if you have more fields add them to the output below //

    $output = "poblacio,tipus,data-entrada,data-sortida,PrimerCognom,SegonCognom,nom,Sexe,data-naixament,identificacio,Adreca,CodiPostal,Ciutat,Provincia,Pais,Telefon,Mobil,email,Estudis,Curs,Centre,Familiar,NIF-familiar,professio-familiar,Adreca-familiar,CodiPostal-familiar,Poblacio-familiar,Provincia-familiar,Pais-familiar,Mail-familiar,Telefon-familiar,Mobil-familiar,questionari-coneixament,questionari-aficions,accepto,num-registre,maildesti,titol,url,arxiu-dni,arxiu-universitat,arxiu-pagament,arxiu-dni-url,arxiu-universitat-url,arxiu-pagament,url,Submitted From,data,accepta-politica,ip,navegador";
    $output .= "\n";
    $output .= $_POST["residencia"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["menu-147"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["date-5"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["date-6"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-145"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-4445"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-144"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["radio-603"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["date-34"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-146"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-147"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-1478"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-149"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-150"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["menu-950"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-151"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-1521"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["email-775"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-200"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-201"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-202"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-301"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-302"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-313"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-303"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-304"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-305"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["menu-951"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-306"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-309"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-308"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-3048"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-543"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["text-697"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["Si"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["cf7-coutner"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["reserves@sample.com"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["Formulario recibido"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["https://www.sample.com"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["file-628"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["file-629"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["file-630"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST[""] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST[""] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST[""] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["1"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["_date"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["Si"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["_remote_ip"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["_user_agent"] . ", ";
    $output .= $_POST["your-email"];
    // Save contents to file //
    file_put_contents($user_register_csv, $output);

}
// Clear file/user data after submission //
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
  $user_register_csv = 'wp-content/uploads/csvs/csvreserva.csv';
  file_put_contents($user_register_csv, '');
  // File cleared and ready to be rewritten on next submission //
});
// Remember - add the above path to the WPCF7 File attachment setting within the relevant form //
```

Comment: By using the _proper_ function PHP already provides for writing CSV data, instead of assembling the line to write to the file manually. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I think the guy that commented on you post has a better solution but alternatively you can add this line before you assign a value to $output

```
$_POST = str_replace(",","",$_POST);
```

This will replace all the commas in $_POST with an empty character so even if the user enters a comma it will get replaced with an empty character.

If you want to keep the commas that the user enters, you can enclose the $_POST variable in quotation marks when extending the value of the $output variable. For example:

```
$output .= '"'.$_POST["residencia"].'", ';
```